# Python coloredlogs not working in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, flask, logging

I'm trying to use coloredlogs within a Flask application

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
coloredlogs.install(logger=logger)
```

The colored logs are produced when I run python app.py.

However, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000

ENV NAME OpentoAll

CMD [ "python", "app.py"]
```

when I build a docker image and run it, logs are outputted however they are not colored.

For reference, I have coloredlogs, colorama and humanfriendly in my requirements.

```
coloredlogs==15.0.1
colorama
humanfriendly==9.2
```

Is there another package I'm missing for colors to work in a Docker image? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when running inside docker, you don't have a tty.

You can configure it to run with a tty for your docker/docker-compose/kubernetes environment, but it's easier to use the following:

```
coloredlogs.install(logger=logger, isatty=True)
```

This will ensure that it always outputs with color codes.